# How to add multiple paths?

Tags: syntax, visualization

What I am trying to do is generate random data based on a normal distribution and plot different paths of the process. But how can I add multiple paths instead of repeating the process over and over and storing it in variables?
Here is the code and image for reference:

```
In[100]:= Randnmbr = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000];
          Randnmbr2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2], 1000];
          CumulativePlus = Join[{0}, Accumulate[Randnmbr ]];
          CumulativePlus2 = Join[{0}, Accumulate[Randnmbr2]];
          ListLinePlot[{CumulativePlus, CumulativePlus2},PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000]], 10]]
```

[image]